# Is this correct to pass this keyword as parameter for member objects creation in java?

Tags: java

Here is my definition of class

```
class A {
    B b = new B(this);
}
```

Is it correct to pass `this` keyword as parameter for member 
objects creation in the class' definition?

if yes where can we use this?

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what do you mean by "correct"?

Comment: if B is using A objcet in itself then you can pass it

Comment: Have you tried writing something that failed, or are you just being lazy?

Comment: i know that this code works, but i want to know if this has any good design significance?

Comment: It has bad design significance.

Answer (score 4):

It is correct in the sense that it compiles and runs.

It may be dangerous because your object is not fully initialized, so using it inside the member object's constructor may not be safe.

At a higher level, it's a bad practice to create new objects in constructor, see Injection of Dependencies pattern.

Update: this code certainly compiles:

```
class B {
    B(A a) {

    }
}

class A{
    B b = new B(this);
}
```

Comment: "It is correct in the sense that it compiles and runs." You have no way of knowing that given the information provided. Please do not provide answers to heavily underspecified questions.

Comment: The essence of the question is whether `B b = new B(this);` is correct. I think my answer addresses this. I also mention it's not advisable.

Comment: Thanks much @Arkadiy

Comment: If you don't see a definition of B, how can you know this?

Answer (score 0):

If you had some kind of context object which is always created, you could use this pattern to avoid using an inner class.

So instead of this:

```
class A {
    B b = new B();
    class B {
        void printA() { System.out.println(A.this); }
    }
}
```

You could have two separate files:

```
class A {
    B b = new B(this);
}

class B {
    A a;
    B(A a) { this.a = a; }
    void printA() { System.out.println(a); }
}
```